# Using my browser to make Vimeo Api request

Tags: json, browser, vimeo, vimeo-api

This is not a complicated question at all so hopefully someone can answer this for me. I'm trying to make a request to the Vimeo api in my browser by doing something like this : `api.vimeo.com/videos/207310265`. This works in vimeo's api playground but in the browser I'm being told that I need a valid authenticated access token, which I have, I just don't know where/how to put in the url. If anyone could help me with this that would be awesome!

Comment: Authorization: Bearer <OAUTH_TOKEN> set this in your ajax header options.

Answer (score 1):

You can call to vimeo API from browser with access token

```
  $.ajax({ 
      .... 
      .....
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
         xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+token);        
      }
    });
```